# How to get first characters matching results only in typeahead

Tags: javascript, typeahead

I only want to show the results starting from user entered matching characters only. I want to avoid if they occur in the middle. How can I do this in typeahead.

Here's my js code:

```
var cities = new Bloodhound({
  datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  prefetch: '/getcities'
});

$('#city').typeahead({
    hint: true,
    highlight: true,
    minLength: 3,
    limit: 10
}, {
  name: 'cities',
  source: cities
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to redefine datumTokenizer. This is an example assuming your autocompletion values are for the field "key" in an array of objects

```
datumTokenizer: function(d){
                        var tokens = [];
                        var stringSize = d.key.length;                            
                        for (var i = 0; i<= stringSize; i++){
                              tokens.push(d.key.substr(0, i));
                          }
                        return tokens;
                    },
```